# Adding custom fields to a class at runtime, in Ruby with mongoid

Tags: ruby-on-rails, validation, mongoid, custom-fields

In a project came across a requirement wherein a logged in user should be asked specific data based on his  company. This specific data would be company specific, and could be mandatory or unique. This is the approach I took.
1. Defined a model to with three fields: Label (string), Mandatory(boolean), Unique(boolean).
2. The admin of the company could then enter the required fields for. e.g: `Label => "Employee number", Mandatory => true, Unique => false using a simple form.`
3. This data should be asked at the time of creating another record of model Redeemed Coupon for logged in user.
4. So during initialize of the Redeemed Coupon model, reopening the class, and checking the logged in user's company.

```
 class RedeemedCoupon
  def initialize(attrs = nil, options = nil)
    super
    if Merchant.current #this is set in the application controller as thread specific variable

  coupon_custom_field = CouponCustomField.where(:merchant_id => Merchant.current).first
  if coupon_custom_field and coupon_custom_field.custom_fields.size > 0
    coupon_custom_field.custom_fields.each do |custom_field|
      class_eval do
        field custom_field.label.to_sym, :type => String
        attr_accessible custom_field.label.to_sym
      end
      if custom_field.unique
        class_eval do
          index custom_field.label.to_sym
          #validates_uniqueness_of custom_field.label.to_sym, :case_sensitive => false
        end
      end
      if custom_field.mandatory
        class_eval do
          #validates_presence_of custom_field.label.to_sym
        end
      end
    end
  end
end
```

end

However the validations validates presence of and uniqueness does not work, with a failure message being given : callback not defined. this is thrown before save, when is_valid? is called object.
TO work around that 
Put in custom validation

```
 validate :custom_mandatory_unique

 def custom_mandatory_unique
   if Merchant.current
     coupon_custom_field = CouponCustomField.where(:ira_merchant_id => Merchant.current).first
   if coupon_custom_field and coupon_custom_field.custom_fields.size > 0
     coupon_custom_field.custom_fields.each do |custom_field|
       field_value = self.send(custom_field.label.to_sym)
       self.errors.add(custom_field.label.to_sym, "cannot be blank") if !field_value.present? and  custom_field.mandatory

      if field_value.present? and custom_field.unique
        if RedeemedCoupon.where(custom_field.label.to_sym => field_value, :merchant_id => Merchant.current).size > 0
          self.errors.add(custom_field.label.to_sym, "already taken")
        end
      end
    end
  end 
end
```

end

My questions:
1. Is this the best way of doing it.
2. Are there any gems already present (have searched, however couldnt get any)?
3. How can i use the validation helpers here instead of defining a seperate validate block?

Comment: This seams like an extremely complicated way to handle business logic. Validations are not supposed to be inserted at run time. Surely you can do it, but it's hard to justify it from many points: performance, maintainability, etc

Comment: Have you looked at https://github.com/locomotivecms/custom_fields? It doesn't include validations though.

Answer (score 0):

I would define a model that stores the set of attribute mappings that correspond to a company, and an attribute model that holds its values and is associated with your coupon model. Then create a custom validation method in coupon that makes sure all of the require attributes are present based on the company id, and a method that builds them per the company association.